# What is the use of :: operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Please give me **examples** and **usages** of **::** **operator** in **Kotlin**

Comment: [:: creates a member reference or a class reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols). Examples of [function references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) and [class references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)

Comment: Try to find out such things yourself by playing around with them. If you really have a problem with it, than you should post it here.

Answer (score 1):

One example: It's for [function references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), that can be used alternatively to lambdas in many places:

```
 //Function expecting a lambda to be passed
fun <T> applyToList(list: List<T>, func: (T) -> Boolean) = list.filter { it -> func(it) }

fun foo(i: Int): Boolean = i > 3
//call applyToList with reference to foo()
applyToList(list, ::foo)
```

Or the same with lambda:

```
 applyToList(sub) { it > 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this one used while using intent

```
 val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.