# Equivalent of syntax `!::someReference` in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, operators

Going through [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin) Android Doc, I saw this piece of code:

```
fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    if (!::users.isInitialized) {
        users = MutableLiveData()
        loadUsers()
    }
    return users
}
```

I am aware about the use of `::` operator for  creating a member reference or a class reference. But what is the code equivalent of `!::users.isInitialized` syntax?

P.S: This is not duplicate of [What is the use of :: operator in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461742/what-is-the-use-of-operator-in-kotlin)

Comment: A logical NOT of a boolean value returned from `user.isInitialized` - ?

Comment: How it is different from (!user.isinitialized)?

Comment: Note that [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) has been updated to avoid this code construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example from the Android Docs is a `lateinit` variable `users` some lines above your snippet:

```
private lateinit var users: MutableLiveData<List<User>>
```

The syntax `::users.isInitialized` checks if the lateinit variable  `users` is already initialized, see [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized-since-12) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

`::` is a short form for `this::` in Kotlin.

`::` is a operator to creates a member reference or a class reference.

It is also used to [Check whether a lateinit var is initialized](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized) or to get [Bound Class References](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11)

Since Kotlin 1.2, explicitly specifying `this` as the receiver is not necessary: `this::` and `::` are equivalent.

You can view the [docs examples](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) for clear understanding of the same.